# Why are laser pulses Sech Squared in temporal shape?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, semiconductor-physics, laser

Ultrashort pulses from mode-locked lasers often have a temporal shape which can be described with a [squared hyperbolic secant ($\mathrm{sech}^2$) function:](http://www.rp-photonics.com/sech2_shaped_pulses.html)

$$
P(t)=P_0 \mathrm{sech}^2 \left( \frac{t}{\tau} \right) = \frac{P_0}{\mathrm{cosh}^2\left( \frac{t}{\tau} \right)}
$$

This fucntion looks similar to but is subtly different from the [Gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) (normal distribution) function. The Gaussian function shows up in many different physical phenomenon and its appearance can be explained by the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

Is there a similar theorem or theory to explain the appearance of the $\mathrm{sech}^2$ fuction in pulsed laser dynamics.

Comment: I've just added a last paragraph, which may explain why you're thinking about Gaussian beams in optics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ${\rm sech}$ pulse is, in Kerr effect nonlinear optical mediums, an [Optical Soliton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton_%28optics%29).

This means that it is the particular time variation such that the tendency of the pulse to spread out in time owing to linear dispersion is exactly counterbalanced by the nonlinear effect that tends to confine pulses in time. This balance is a stable one in a Kerr medium, meaning that small perturbations of the ${\rm sech}$ pulse tend to decay. Alternatively, a pulse that looks vaguely like a ${\rm sech}$ pulse will evolve towards the latter. This means that, at high power, the nonlinear lasing medium will tend to produce ${\rm sech}$ pulses. The Kerr model, where the refractive index varies like $n_0 + \kappa |\vec{E}|^2$ (where $\vec{E}$ is the electric field envelope) is a good first approximation to many nonlinear mediums.

As you can see, this has nothing to do with the central limit theorem, which explains the emergence of Gaussian probability distributions from the summing, or general linear operations, on a large number of identically distributed random variables. The other way that Gaussian shapes arise in optics is as a *transverse spatial* variation in the [Gaussian Beam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam) because Gaussian and related transverse spatial variations are modal solutions to the paraxial wave equation, or, equivalently, they are "like" eigenfunctions of the Fresnel diffraction integral insofar that a diffracted Gaussian beam is also a Gaussian beam (with different parameters, so we're not quite talking eigenfunctions here) and, to first approximation, a paraxial Gaussian beam passing through a thin lens or reflected from a large radius spherical mirror is also a Gaussian beam. So Gaussian beams are the eigenfunctions of a laser cavity: they are the ones left invariant by a round trip through the cavity.

Comment: It's important to note here that optical solitons only occur in anomalously dispersive media, i.e., where shorter wavelengths have lower group velocity dispersion than longer. As the Kerr effect is positive, anomalous dispersion is required to counteract it and form a soliton. If the dispersion is normal (longer wavelengths having lower group velocity than shorter) then the Kerr nonlinearity and dispersion act together to break the pulse apart unless care is taken to remove the nonlinear *and* dispersive spectral phase per roundtrip of the laser using a prism compressor, for example.

Comment: Pulses generated in normally dispersive media *can* have a Gaussian temporal shape, and are usually best approximated this way as sech pulses aren't possible in this dispersion regime. I think this might just be a forced approximation though to make the time-frequency analysis easier in practise (more simple Fourier transform shapes), and not based on the central limit theorem. However, there are other solutions to the propagation equations depending on the strength of the nonlinearity, and sometimes even parabolic pulse envelopes are the most appropriate for normally dispersive media.

Comment: @JamesFeehan There's some interesting stuff in your comments. My knowledge of this kind of stuff essentially ends with the nonlinear Schrödinger equation for a Kerr medium, which was the starting point for most of the people I worked with at the time I was looking at this stuff (mid nineties at the ANU with Nail Akmediev, Adrian Ankiewicz and friends). Right off the top of my head I can't quite see where your comments would invalidate (or add more detail to) the simple derivation of the Kerr medium NLSE, although I'm sure they do.

Comment: Nothing I wrote invalidates the GNLSE, but each situation is given by different solutions to it under different dispersion regimes and nonlinear strengths. The reason I stress the importance for anomalous dispersion in soliton generation is that the sech shape is only an analytic solution to the GNLSE if you have anomalous dispersion. For any other case solitons don't form.

Comment: I was being a bit pedantic, basically! People still say they have sech pulses even for dispersion regimes where it's not possible because it means they can use the sech deconvolution factor when converting from autocorrelation duration to pulse duration, which gives them shorter calculated pulse durations (and therefore higher impact results!)

Answer (score 0):

The hyperbolic secant pulse envelope for the electric field (which gives $sech^2(t/t_0)$ pulse envelope for intensity) is obtained from the solution of the pendulum equation ($d^2 \theta/dt^2 - \sin(\theta)/t_0^2 = 0$ ).

The pendulum equation describes 2-level atoms interacting with a monochromatic pulse with slowly varying envelope (varying slowly compared to the optical frequency, but still possibly "ultrafast"). Here, theta is the area of the pulse. So if the laser pulse is shorter than the dephasing time of the atoms/molecules that produce the light, then the interaction producing the light is coherent and is well described by the Optical Bloch equations, which give the pendulum equation.

References:

- Eqn. 4.19 in Allen and Eberly, Optical Resonance and Two-Level Atoms;
- SL McCall and EL Hahn, Phys Rev Lett 18, 908 (1967).