# Why laser pulses are often assumed to have a hyperbolic secant shape

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, laser

For mathematical simplicity we often assume that the laser pulses have a Gaussian envelope. But many theoretical models still predict hyperbolic secant pulse shapes for the laser. Any particular reason for that?
I know secant profile has stronger wings in temporal domain than gaussian profile. But other than that what could be the reason for this assumption?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149233/why-are-laser-pulses-sech-squared-in-temporal-shape